# How can I avoid repetition in declaring similar types?

Tags: f#

I have the following code:

`type CapturablePieces = Pawn | Knight | Bishop | Rook | Queen`

I can define another type as follows:

`type Pieces = Pawn | Knight | Bishop | Rook | Queen | King`

However, there is obviously a lot of code repetition here. Is there a way to avoid this by incorporating `CapturablePieces` into the definition of `Pieces`?

Comment: `type Pieces = Capturable of CapturablePieces | King` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't need CapturablePieces to be separable type, just some subset of particular cases, maybe it can be implemented as member? I can think of two ways:

a) Collection of capturable pieces in static member:

```
type Pieces = Pawn | Knight | Bishop | Rook | Queen | King
    static member Capturable = [Pawn; Knight; Bishop; Rook; Queen]
```

b) Boolean member:

```
type Pieces = Pawn | Knight | Bishop | Rook | Queen | King
    member x.IsCapturable = match x with King -> false | _ -> true
```